# Automatic height constraint formed on tableview cell when there are constraints for collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to build a Instagram feed like view where there is a TableView and each cell represent a post. Each cell contains a collectionView of images, page control, and things like comments, likes underneath.

I want my images to always be in same size so I set the constraints for height and width

However, when my images are loaded and I call reloadTable for my TableView, the height of the cells are getting random constraint added.

P.S: I also set these in the viewdidload that has the tableView

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 520
```

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this constraint or fix the height to be adaptive?:

```
.ImageHomeTableViewCell:0x7fcbd7862800'ImageHomeTableViewCell'.height == 43.5   (active)
```

Comment: If you want to fix the dimension, don't use `UITableView.automaticDimension` rather use `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: @iphonic I do not want to fix it because there is a descriptionLabel which can vary in line number.

Comment: OK then look for you have correct bottom constraint which restricts the cell to resize beyond the required dimension.. You can check the cell by toggling the automatic height property from the storyboard for the cell.